# Display files that have been uploaded to directory (servlet)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, file-upload

So, I followed this tutorial to upload files to a servlet:
http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/java-file-upload-example-with-servlet-30-api
It creates a folder (if it doesn't exist) and uploads a file to that folder.
Once the upload in complete it displays a page saying that the upload was successful. I've seen other tutorials, such as this one:
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/servlet-upload-file-and-download-file-example.html
That display a download link, but only for the file that was just uploaded.
I want to create a page that uploaded a file, then displays links to download all files that have been uploaded (or a button to direct one to such a page).

Comment: You'll have to keep reference to all the files that users have uploaded, then retrieve that reference and display it to your users.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you're uploading all files to X folder

Then, Simply iterate over X folder to get all files

```
for(File f:new File("X").listFiles()){
  //Iterate here to create download links for each file
}
```

You may use http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/servlet-upload-file-and-download-file-example.html for each of the file to create a download link